# Why does Hibernate trigger onFlushDirty twice?

Tags: castle-activerecord

Lately I have been using the Castle ActiveRecord framework a lot and it has worked fine until I found some strange behaviour: the onFlushDirty is triggered twice in some situations. It is even triggered when I make a simple query. I'm really confused cause I'm trying to create auditing data in onFlushDirty and as I read data it's triggered which causes it to save identical data.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Try to define "some situations". Try to isolate the issue in a stand-alone testcase. Also, is there any chance you're using flushmode.auto *and* also flushing manually?

Comment: I'm not setting FlushMode, I think is set to the default behaviour, however I have seen this; I have a field named "AddressCountryMode" which is null in database and when onFlushDirty is triggered the previousState is "null" and currentState is 0, is that the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved my issue but I don't know why this happens.

First of all, the data I have in database has null values in some date fields and integer fields, (the data came from a migration from Btrieve).

When I loaded the data in a datagrid the onFlushDirty event triggered, when I debugged and watched the data I saw that on a date field with null value it had a previousState with null and currentState with '0001-01-01 00:00:00'. I changed in the database the nulls with '0001-01-01 00:00:00' in the case of date fields and zero for the integer fields and the onFlushDirty event never triggered again when I loaded the data on the datagrid.

But the question still remains. Why does this happens or is it correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've told Hibernate (in the mapping for that table or an annotation on the entity class) that the date field should not be null, so Hibernate sets it for you, but since this differs from the value it retrieved from the database, it's marked as dirty.

I've also run into the situation where Hibernate flushes the Session several times before committing, which causes any logic in onFlushDirty to be run more times than I wanted. This was happening because when the session is set to FlushMode.AUTO, the session is flushed prior to retrieval in order to include recent uncommitted changes. This is [by design](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HB-1480), so I began committing immediately after making changes to be audited.